# True/False.... still dealing cards?

Tags: php

Why is the instance still dealing cards? Even though clearly, the $isDealer tag is defaulted to false, except for the dealer?

```
$cards = array('Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack','Queen','King');
$suits = array('Hearts','Diamonds','Spades','Clubs');

class Person {
public $isDealer = false;
public $luck = 15;

public function dealCards() {
    if ($isDealer) {

        global $cards;
        global $suits;

        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $pulledcard = rand(0,count($cards)-1);
            $pulledsuit = rand(0,count($suits)-1);
            echo $dealt = $cards[$pulledcard] .' of '. $suits[$pulledsuit] . '<br>';
        }
    }
    else {
        return 'You\'re not a dealer';
        }
    }
}

class Baller extends Person { public $luck = 50; }
class Dealer extends Person { public $isDealer = true; }

$dealer = new Dealer();
$theman = new Baller();
$random = new Person();

echo $theman->dealCards();       //this should return you're not a dealer but it deals cards instead
```

The last part should return a "You're not a dealer!" but instead, it deals cards. The same goes with the actual "Dealer".

Comment: This is not the way to do it. `dealCards()` should be in the Dealer class.

Comment: Why are you using `global`? That's a very bad idea.

Comment: c'mon guys, isDealer is clearly not a class, it's defined and used procedurally

Comment: @Mike Thanks, but what's wrong with it? I didn't want to create an array every time the function was called. This way, the variables are only declared once.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was thinking about that as well. I might as well do that.

Comment: @Richard check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions

Answer (score 5):

You want

```
if ($this->isDealer) {
```

Comment: Yep, @user3084341, you need to use $this-> to reference a class variable!

Answer (score 1):

`$isDealer` does not mean `$this->isDealer`. It means a new, implicitly-created variable.

Plus, you can't override member variables like that.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
if ($isDealer)
```

You are not checking the value for the variable that you expect. Your code is asking whether the variable `$isDealer` within the scope of the function `dealCards()` exists or is true/false. In order to check whether the member variable `$isDealer` for the class `Person` is true/false you must use `$this->isDealer`. This ensures that you are checking the member variable `$isDealer` within the cope of `Person` and not within the scope of the member function. So, you should get the behavior you expect if you use

```
if ($this->isDealer)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have this line:

```
class Dealer extends Person { public $isDealer = true; }
```

is it possible that `public $isDealer = true;` will overwrite the `public $isDealer` in class Person{}, having it that $isDealer will always be true? from another point of view, if this script is the only place where you use $isDealer, it might not be really necessary to define it as public?